# check if received specific SMS

Tags: ios, swift, sms, message

For my App I need to check if a message (sms) from a specific number has been received, but I don't know at all how to check that? I already searched the internet, but without any helpful answer. Does someone know how to do that? The thing is that my company sends test SMS to the phone and when the phone received the SMS, it should start doing something (which doesn't have to do anything with that so I leave it out)... So is there a possibility to do that? Btw I am programming in swift and I know it's not nice to ask for sample code, but since I have no clue at all, some sample code would be nice!

Comment: There is no way an app can access the text messages that have been received by the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Apple handles SMS messages inside it's Messages app, and does not expose information about the messages received to third party apps.